# Save input field contact form 7 to post meta

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to calculate the inventory down to zero via storing the input of a number field.

So far i have the following:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail',
    function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
       $post_id = get_the_id();
       $voorraad = '';
       if ($post_id === 5080){
       $voorraad = get_post_meta(5080,'voorraad',true);
       $newvoorraad = implode( ', ', (array) $submission->get_posted_data( 'number-435' ));
       $stock = $voorraad - $newvoorraad;
       update_post_meta($post_id, 'voorraad', $stock);
         }
    },10,3
    );
```

However, this does not work.

The meta field voorraad exists and has value 450. However, the field is not updated after input. I cannot store the submitted data in the first place, even if i use an empty meta field with a different name and store a set string like 'example', only for testing purposes.

How can i store a user input in a meta field upon submission?

Any ideas?

Comment: is $voorraad and $newvoorraad numeric?

Comment: Yes but challenge is to make update post meta working as it doesnt update anything. No string, no number. Tried it all...

Answer (score 0):

The `get_the_id()` function won't retrieve the postID from the form.  You have to get that from the `$submission->get_meta('container_post_id)`

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail',
    function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
        $post_id = $submission->get_meta('container_post_id');
        $voorraad = '';
        if ($post_id === 5080){
            $voorraad = get_post_meta(5080,'voorraad',true);
            $newvoorraad = implode( ', ', (array) $submission->get_posted_data( 'number-435' ));
            $stock = $voorraad - $newvoorraad;
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'voorraad', $stock);
        }
    },10,3
);
```

**Method #2**

Another Method would be to use the contact form ID as the trigger, and just place your post ID in the form.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail',
    function ($contact_form) {
        if ($contact_form->id() === 123) { // Your Contact Form ID
            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
            $voorraad = '';
            $voorraad = get_post_meta(5080, 'voorraad', true);
            $newvoorraad = implode(', ', (array)$submission->get_posted_data('number-435'));
            $stock = $voorraad - $newvoorraad;
            update_post_meta(5080, 'voorraad', $stock);
        }
    }
);
```